# Lepus: "lepusculus". Longus: "longusculus" or "longiculus"

Tags: classical-latin, diminutive

-iculus or -usculus for "Longus"?, please

Answer (score 5):

There is the word [*longulus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=longulus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), "rather long".
Whether that is appropriate depends on what you want to mean by the word.
I understand "small hare" but "small long" is far less clear.
I can't even tell whether you want a noun or an adjective.

My method for finding such a word was simple:
Open a good dictionary ([online](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) or printed) at words starting with *long-* and look for something that looks like a diminutive.